# Why Octopus doesn't wait the cloudformation stack to complete?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, octopus-deploy

Octopus deploy doesn't wait the cloudformation stack to complete and pass to the next step with empty variables.

Could somebody tell me how can i make octopus to wait ?

PS: I have selected the checbox "Wait for completion"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug and the issue [#4345][1] was created to resolve it. The problem occurs only with nested stacks. Octopus exit the step immediately when it catches the first stack created event.